# How to add a parent node using foreach

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have got a big trouble in my Xml generator using C#. I could not find how to add a parent node containing the element's name.

The information is coming from a database and inserted into the Xml document in memory. I have to get those nodes by name because I will need to convert some of them.

Code:

```
XmlElement xe = xd.CreateElement("xe");

foreach (XmlNode node in xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    XmlNode imported = xd.ImportNode(node, true);
    xe.AppendChild(imported["a"]);
    xe.AppendChild(imported["b"]);
    xe.AppendChild(imported["c"]);
    xe.AppendChild(imported["d"]);
}
```

Result:

```
<node>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <d>4</d>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <d>4</d>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <d>4</d>
</node>
```

What I need:

```
<node>
    <ex>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>2</b>
        <c>3</c>
        <d>4</d>
    </ex>
    <ex>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>2</b>
        <c>3</c>
        <d>4</d>
    </ex>
    <ex>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>2</b>
        <c>3</c>
        <d>4</d>
    </ex>
</node>
```

Comment: where are you creating '<ex>' node ?

Comment: before the foreach....

if I insert that into the foreachm, it's run ok:

                XmlNode imported = xd.ImportNode(node, true);
                imported.ParentNode.AppendChild(imported );

But... I need to get each one by name to convert them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the children to an element named "ex", then append that element to the root

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        XmlNode imported = xd.ImportNode(node, true);
        XmlElement ex = xd.CreateElement("ex");
        ex.AppendChild(imported["a"]);
        ex.AppendChild(imported["b"]);
        ex.AppendChild(imported["c"]);
        ex.AppendChild(imported["d"]);
        xd.AppendChild(ex);
    }
```

Comment: @BiancaFonseca If this solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer (click the tick on the top left of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
    XmlElement xe = xd.CreateElement("xe");

    foreach (XmlNode node in xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        XmlNode imported = xd.ImportNode(node, true);

        XmlElement child = xd.CreateElement("ex");

        child.AppendChild(imported["a"]);
        child.AppendChild(imported["b"]);
        child.AppendChild(imported["c"]);
        child.AppendChild(imported["d"]);

        xe.AppendChild(child); 

    }
```